# MySQL: remove substrings containing numerals

Tags: mysql

I have a column in a MySQL table that has a string that is made up of a code and a title and I need to split them into two separate columns.

At the moment, only the `title` column has data. I can copy `title` into `code` but then I want to remove substrings containing numerals from the `title` column and remove substrings *not* containing numerals from the `code` column.

An example value looks like *NWAB110438 Lagoon* and I want *NWAB110438* to be in `code` and *Lagoon* in `title`.

I know how to select records containing numerals, but not how to remove substrings that contain a numeral.

**EDIT**

I should also add that sometimes the substring with the numeral will be after the substring without it, and sometimes the column will contain just a single substring, so the following are all possible values:

- NWAB110438 Lagoon
- Lagoon NWAB110438
- Lagoon
- NWAB110438

So it seems like substring_index won't always match the correct value.

Comment: Is there space between `NWAB110438` and `Lagoon` ?

Comment: Yes there is a space between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using SUBSTRING_INDEX, INSTR, REGEXP, with a complete demo.

SQL:

```
-- data
create table t1(title varchar(100), code varchar(100));
insert into t1 values
('NWAB110438 Lagoon', 'NWAB110438 Lagoon'),
('Lagoon NWAB110438', 'Lagoon NWAB110438'),
('Lagoon', 'Lagoon'),
('NWAB110438', 'NWAB110438');
select * from t1;

-- query wanted
UPDATE t1
SET 
    title = TRIM(CONCAT(IF((@first := SUBSTRING_INDEX(title, ' ', 1)) REGEXP '[0-9]+', '', @first), 
                        ' ', 
                        IF((@second := IF(INSTR(title, ' '), SUBSTRING_INDEX(title, ' ', -1), '')) REGEXP '[0-9]+', '', @second))),
    code = TRIM(CONCAT(IF(@first REGEXP '[0-9]+', @first, ''), 
                        ' ', 
                        IF(@second REGEXP '[0-9]+', @second, '')));
select * from t1;
```

Output:

```
mysql> select * from t1;
+-------------------+-------------------+
| title             | code              |
+-------------------+-------------------+
| NWAB110438 Lagoon | NWAB110438 Lagoon |
| Lagoon NWAB110438 | Lagoon NWAB110438 |
| Lagoon            | Lagoon            |
| NWAB110438        | NWAB110438        |
+-------------------+-------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> UPDATE t1
    -> SET
    ->     title = TRIM(CONCAT(IF((@first := SUBSTRING_INDEX(title, ' ', 1)) REGEXP '[0-9]+', '', @first),
    ->                         ' ',
    ->                         IF((@second := IF(INSTR(title, ' '), SUBSTRING_INDEX(title, ' ', -1), '')) REGEXP '[0-9]+', '', @second))),
    ->     code = TRIM(CONCAT(IF(@first REGEXP '[0-9]+', @first, ''),
    ->                         ' ',
    ->                         IF(@second REGEXP '[0-9]+', @second, '')));
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 4  Changed: 4  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from t1;
+--------+------------+
| title  | code       |
+--------+------------+
| Lagoon | NWAB110438 |
| Lagoon | NWAB110438 |
| Lagoon |            |
|        | NWAB110438 |
+--------+------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case i will suggest to use php to do the separate function.
For pure MySQL, i found a link that might help you.

*SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('www.mytestpage.info','.',2);*

http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring_index-function.php

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use `substring_index()` to extract a part of a string.